# Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:downloadBoost'

Tags: react-native, expo

#### Summary

When running `npx expo run:android` android build fails with this error. See logs:
[image: Logs]

Tried to install `expo-modules-core` explicitly.
Tried upgrading Gradle plugin from 7.1.1 up to 7.3.3 and 7.5.

Did not find any more solutions on the internet.

Any idea what to do?

Related github issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19596

#### What platform(s) does this occur on?

Android

#### SDK Version

46

#### Environment

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 12.6
      Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.14.2 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 8.5.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 16.0, macOS 12.3, tvOS 16.0, watchOS 9.0
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
      Xcode: 14.0.1/14A400 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      @expo/metro-config: ^0.4.0 => 0.4.0 
      expo: ~46.0.16 => 46.0.16 
      react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
      react-dom: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
      react-native: 0.69.6 => 0.69.6 
      react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.9 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 2.4.1
      expo-cli: 6.0.6
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

#### Minimal reproducible example

Package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "debug": "open 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=19000'",
    "debug dev": "open 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081'"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/raleway": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.0",
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.4.0",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.7",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.6",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.6",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.2.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "expo": "~46.0.16",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.2.2",
    "expo-background-fetch": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.3.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "expo-dev-client": "1.3.1",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-image-loader": "~3.2.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-keep-awake": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "~0.10.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-screen-capture": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-task-manager": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.10.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-agora": "^3.7.1",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1289.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "sentry-expo": "~5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "expo-module-scripts": "^2.1.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^46.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "standard-version-expo/**/@expo/config-plugins": "4.1.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "hammashelppi-app",
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Hammashelppi",
    "slug": "hammashelppi",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./images/HH_Logo.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./images/HH_splash_image.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#107CA2"
    },
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "developmentClient": {
      "silentLaunch": true
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": [
        "expo.ts",
        "expo.tsx",
        "expo.js",
        "expo.jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "wasm",
        "svg"
      ]
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 300000,
      "enabled": true,
      "url": "https://u.expo.dev/****"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./images/favicon.png"
    },
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "hammashelppi",
            "project": "hammashelppi",
            "authToken": "***"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "@stripe/stripe-react-native",
        {
          "merchantIdentifier": "***",
          "enableGooglePay": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "Allow Hammashelppi to access your gallery.",
          "cameraPermission": "Allow Hammashelppi to access your camera."
        }
      ],
      ["expo-camera"],
      [
        "expo-notifications",
        {
          "icon": "./images/HH_android_notifications_white.png",
          "color": "#107CA2",
          "mode": "production"
        }
      ],
      "sentry-expo",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 31,
            "buildToolsVersion": "30.0.2",
            "kotlinVersion": "1.7.10"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "android": {
      "icon": "./images/HH_android_logo_old.png",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./images/HH_android_logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#107CA2"
      },
      "package": "***",
      "versionCode": 15,
      "permissions": [
        "NOTIFICATIONS",
        "CAMERA",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.CAMERA"
      ],
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "***",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSFaceIDUsageDescription": "Face ID is used for authentication",
        "UIBackgroundModes": ["fetch", "remote-notification"]
      },
      "buildNumber": "15",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
    },
    "runtimeVersion": "2.0.0",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "***"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.52.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",    
    },
    "development-android": {
      "extends": "development",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk",
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "development-ios": {
      "extends": "development",
      "ios": {
        "enterpriseProvisioning": "universal"
      },
      "cache": {
        "key": "18999"
      }
    },

    "preview-android": {
      "extends": "development",
      "channel": "preview-android",
      "developmentClient": false,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle",
        "gradleCommand": ":app:bundleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview-ios": {
      "extends": "development",
      "channel": "preview-ios",
      "developmentClient": false,
      "ios": {
        "enterpriseProvisioning": "universal",
        "image": "latest"
      },
      "cache": {
        "key": "18999"
      }
    },

    "production-android": {
      "extends": "development",
      "distribution": "store",
      "channel": "production-android",
      "developmentClient": false
    },
    "production-ios": {
      "extends": "development",
      "distribution": "store",
      "channel": "production-ios",
      "developmentClient": false
    }
  },
  "submit": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is not in your project, the resource with the boost library is not available
https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.tar.bz2

Answer (score 0):

If your kotlin version is `"1.7.20"`
Downgrading it to `"1.6.0"` in  `android/build.gradle` helps
example : `kotlin_version = "1.6.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the Issue with Boost Library

**Step 1**: Update URL in ReactAndroid Build Script

Navigate to the file: /node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build.gradle
Locate the following line:

```
https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/${BOOST_VERSION.replace("_", ".")}/source/boost_${BOOST_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

Replace it with:

```
https://archives.boost.io/release/${BOOST_VERSION.replace("_", ".")}/source/boost_${BOOST_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

**Step 2**: Update URL in Expo Modules Core

Go to the file: /node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/build.gradle.
Search for the same URL as in Step 1.
Replace it with the new URL provided in Step 1.

**Step 3**: Apply the Patches

After making the changes, run the following commands to apply the patches:

patch-package react-native
patch-package expo-modules-core

**Step 4**:
Don't forget to

- reinstall node_modules and package-lock.json
- run cd `android && ./gradlew clean`

credits: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19596#issuecomment-1881613104